# Не сортируется по алфавиту при использовании UNION. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Имеется запрос, который поля начинающиеся с 'КТ-' ставил вначале, а 'КТ-МЛ-' уже после. Но при добавлении новых 'КТ-А..' они не ставятся по алфавиту. Запрос и пример таблицы ниже

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | КТ-Анп/1 |
| 2 | КТ-Бгд/1 |
| 2 | КТ-Бгд/2 |
| 1 | КТ-Анп/2 |
| 1 | КТ-МЛ-Анп/1 |

```
(SELECT `id`, `name` 
 FROM  sl_list 
 WHERE name like "КТ-%" 
   AND name NOT LIKE "%КТ-МЛ-%" 
 ORDER BY `name`) 
UNION 
(select * 
 from sl_list 
 where name like "КТ-МЛ-%" 
 ORDER BY `name`);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, дайте вопросу осмысленный заголовок (нажав [edit])

Comment: [ORDER BY and LIMIT in Unions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-order-by-limit) - читать до полного понимания. PS. ORDER BY без LIMIT в подзапросе игнорируется ВСЕГДА.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> запрос, который поля начинающиеся с 'КТ-' ставил вначале, а 'КТ-МЛ-' уже после

```
SELECT id, name
FROM  sl_list 
ORDER BY name LIKE "%КТ-МЛ-%", name
```

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало

Comment: @DanyaTangens А чего б ему не сработать. `name LIKE "%КТ-МЛ-%"` даёт `1` для тех, кто соответствует шаблону, и `0` для остальных записей.

Answer (score 0):

так попробуйте

```
(SELECT `id`, `name` FROM  sl_list WHERE name like "КТ-%" AND name NOT LIKE "%КТ-МЛ-%" 
 UNION 
select `id`, `name` from sl_list where name like "КТ-МЛ-%")
ORDER BY `name`;
```

Беда в том что вы используете

```
 UNION
```

который объединяет с собирает уникальные записи из двух наборов.
У вас не было бы проблем с сортировкой если бы было

```
 UNION ALL
```

но было с уникальностью.

Так что соберите сначала данные затем отсортируйте и не будет проблем.

Comment: *У вас не было бы проблем с сортировкой если бы было* Это в общем случае неверно. Если суммарная выборка велика, и будет применена материализация, то порядок будет разрушен.

Comment: Внешний запрос - в общем лишний. Без него есть шанс, что всё обойдётся одной сортировкой (особенно если поменять местами поля в списке вывода), а вот с ним - без шансов.

Comment: Спасибо за вашу помощь, я там добавил псевдоним, чтобы не было ошибок. Но он после объединенной таблицы сортирует и получается, что все 'КТ-МЛ-' встают в середину по алфавиту.

Comment: Внешний запрос для наглядности только